# Why is the "\n" character appearing in the matched regex pattern results?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to parse through a log file and extract certain capture groups, such as time-stamps, username's, etc. When I execute the following code, the result is a list element with tuples nested inside as the capture groups (or results of the search). Basically, I was curious why I was getting a '\n' character inside one of my capture groups, I do not want this there.

I tried tinkering with the regex pattern but couldn't fix the problem.

```
import re

with open('obis1-query.log') as myfile:  
    StartTime = []
    myfile = myfile.read()
    mysearch = re.findall('(?P<datetime>\d+-\d+-\d+T\d+:\d+:\d+.\d+-05:00).\s.\w+.\s.\w+:\d.\s.+ecid:\s[A-Za-z\d,:-]+.\s.sik:\s\w+.\s.tid:\s\w+.\s.messageid:\s\w+-\d+.\s.requestid:\s\w+.\s.(?P<sessionid>sessionid:\s\w+).\s.(?P<username>username:\s\w+).\s#+\s\[\[\s-+\sSQL\sRequest,\s(?P<logreqhash>logical\srequest\shash:\n?\w+)', myfile)

if mysearch != None:        
    StartTime.append(mysearch)  
    print(StartTime)
```

The output looks like:

```
[[('2019-06-12T09:14:54.947-05:00', 'sessionid: bf710000', 'username: 
kadaniel', 'logical request hash:\n83bf7e6f'), ('2019-06-12T09:14:55.343- 
05:00', 'sessionid: bf710000', 'username: kadaniel', 'logical request 
hash:\n8e45939b'), ('2019-06-12T09:14:55.362-05:00', 'sessionid: 
bf710000', 'username: kadaniel', 'logical request hash:\n4496de01'),
```

I just want the '\n' character between 'logical request hash:' and 'the following number'(in the last case, 4496de01) to be removed from the results.

Comment: What does the expected output look like?

Comment: The `\n` appears in the results because your match pattern contains it: `hash:\n?\w+`

Comment: @JohnGordon It's supposed to match a line-feed(newline) character, not the literal \n characters.

Comment: @Travis can you explain what you make out the difference between the newline and `\n` to be? I mean, you seem to have the output and you can probably isolate the string in the output that contains the `\n` character in question. Run it through `print()` and see what happens. If it prints in two lines then it's indeed a newline.

Comment: @MichaelEkoka All I'm trying to do is eliminate the \n from the print output in the 4th capture group. In the log file I'm parsing, the format looks like this: -------------------- SQL Request, logical request hash:
83bf7e6f < The f being the last character.

Comment: **If anyone down the road is interested, the answer involved me assigning a re.sub function with str formatting to the mysearch variable**

Answer (score 0):

Consider removing the `\n` character with `.replace("\n", "")`

Comment: I can't use a str method when the result of the capture groups are tuples.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the *entire* file into a string and then searching that string. The file (and therefore the string) contains instances of '\n' which are being matched.

Consider using

```
for line in myfile.readlines():
    # Search line for regex
```

To parse in one line at a time which will inherently leave out the newline identifiers.

Comment: This would not be able to capture `"logical request hash:\n4496de01"` as parts of it are on different lines...